# A puzzle with numbered directions

Tags: riddle

Grandpa said:

"Listen son. Any traveler, who can count, knows his directions.

> South = 1
>
> East = 2
>
> Southwest = 3
>
> So, what is Northwest?"

I should be able to answer this. But.....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*NEWS-flash!* We can make a solid case - in keeping with the theme - that the value of Northwest here is:

> **4** (and not just because of the numeric sequence - read on...)

Because the value attributed to each word is calculated by:

> counting **how many of the 4 cardinal directions' starting letters** (i.e. N, E, S, and W - representing **N**orth, **E**ast, **S**outh, and **W**est) appear within their spelling.
>
>  (NOTE: This is **not** equivalent to counting up how many of a word's letters are N, E, S, or W - see the example of SOUTHWEST below...)
>
>  So in the examples given:
>
>  **S**OUTH = 1 {S}
>  **E**A**S**T = 2 {E,S}
>  **S**OUTH**WES**T = 3 {E,S,W} (NB *not* 4, as the 'S' is repeated)
>
>  Meaning that **N**ORTH**WES**T should be worth 4, as it contains all 4 cardinal directions' starting letters {N,E,S,W}

Note of course that all of this...

> ...gives a second significance to the use of 'numbered directions' in the title. We're not just assigning numbers to directions here, but also counting ('numbering') the directions that appear among their letters!

Answer (score -1):

Call me a crank but I feel this is a pretty dull mathematical puzzle, and the solution is

> $-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{2}$

Because

> I traveled 1 step to the South, 2 steps to the East, and 3 steps to Southwest (in any order), so I traveled $-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{2}$ steps in the direction of Northwest.
>
>  [image]

Comment: This seems to be not in the spirit of the question? It would have been tagged [mathematics] if significant portions were math-based